# OpenGL Transparent textures overlapping/blending issue

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm making a simple 2D game using OpenGL 4.6 in C++. I've currently got both depth testing and blending enabled, where I've been able to render my transparent textures properly. However, when I move one texture to the point that it overlaps another texture, the transparent pixels overlap the texture underneath as well. All my vertices have a z depth value of `0.0f`. Would it be better to just disable depth testing? If not, how can I resolve this?

Initial:
[image]

Overlap:
[image]

Main.cpp:

```
// Initialize application
GLFWwindow *window = init();
if (!window)
    return -1;
// Settings
cout << "OpenGL Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << endl;
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
// Entities
GameUI gameUI;
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, &gameUI);

glm::mat4 Projection {glm::ortho(0.0f, 1280.0f, 0.0f, 720.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)};
glm::mat4 View {glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0, 0, 0))};

glm::vec3 translationA {glm::vec3(0, 0, 0)};
glm::mat4 Model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), translationA);
glm::mat4 mvp = Projection * View * Model;

Shader shader {"shader/vertex.vert", "shader/fragment.frag"};
shader.bind();
shader.setUniformMat4f("MVP", mvp);
int sampler[] {0, 1, 2};
shader.setUniform1iv("v_Textures", sampler, 3);
// MAIN LOOP //
while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gameUI.update();
    gameUI.draw();

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
    // cout << glGetError() << endl;
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 460 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
layout(location = 2) in float texIndex;

out vec2 v_TexCoord;
out float v_TexIndex;

uniform mat4 MVP;

void main() {
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(position, 1.0);
    v_TexCoord = texCoord;
    v_TexIndex = texIndex;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 460 core

in vec2 v_TexCoord;
in float v_TexIndex;

uniform sampler2D v_Textures[3];

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture(v_Textures[int(v_TexIndex)], v_TexCoord);
}
```

Comment: You need to disable the depth test and draw the objects from the back to the front when you use [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending)

Comment: In general, when you use blending you should keep depth test enabled, but disable depth write. In your particular case, you can avoid using depth buffer completely.